# Computing an Integral With Parameters

Tags: integration, induction

Let $p > -1$ and $n \in \Bbb{N} \cup \{0\}$. I am trying to compute the integral

$$\int_{0}^{1} x^{2n+1} (1-x^2)^p dx$$

I suspect that it equals something like $\frac{1}{(1+p)(n+1)^{p+1}}$ (after trying small $n$), but I don't know how to integrate it (I could also be wrong as to my conjecture, since I am awful at arithmetic). It seems like an annoying application of induction and integration by parts, but I could be completely wrong, as integrals are not my forte. Perhaps there is a simpler, more elegant way to calculate the integral. I could use some help.

Comment: Use $t=x^2$ substitution and then [the Beta function.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)

Answer (score 1):

With the substitution $t=1-x^2$, the integral becomes
$$\frac12 \int_0^1(1-t)^nt^p\,\mathrm{d}t $$
This is the beta function but in case you're not familiar with it, you can derive a recurrence relation. Let
$$I_n=\int_0^1(1-t)^nt^p\,\mathrm{d}t \\
I_0=\int_0^1t^p\,\mathrm{d}t=\frac{1}{p+1} $$
$$\begin{align}
I_n&=\int_0^1(1-t)^nt^p\,\mathrm{d}t=\int_0^1(1-t)^{n-1}(1-t)t^p\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int_0^1(1-t)^{n-1}\left(t^p-t^{p+1}\right)\,\mathrm{d}t=I_{n-1}-\int_0^1(1-t)^{n-1}t^{p+1}\,\mathrm{d}t
\end{align}$$
In the last integral in the previous line, use integration by parts with $u=t^{p+1},dv=\left(1-t\right)^{n-1}dt$ to find
$$\int_0^1(1-t)^{n-1}t^{p+1}\,\mathrm{d}t=\frac{p+1}{n}\int_0^1(1-t)^nt^p\,\mathrm{d}t=\frac{p+1}{n}I_n $$
Hence,
$$I_n=I_{n-1}-\frac{p+1}{n}I_n$$
$$I_n=\frac{n}{n+p+1}I_{n-1}=\frac{(n-1)n}{(n+p)(n+p+1)}I_{n-2}=\dots=\frac{1\cdot 2\cdots n}{(p+2)\cdots(n+p+1)}I_0\\
=\frac{n!}{(p+1)(p+2)\cdots(n+p+1)}
$$

The final answer is $\frac12 I_n$.

Comment: Wait, does this work if $p$ is not an integer?

Comment: @user193319 yes. What we're using here is that $n$ is a natural number, so the recurrence $I_n$ eventually terminates with $I_0$

Answer (score 0):

With the substitution $1-x^2=t$, then$-xdx=dt$ and $x^{2n}=(x^2)^n=(1-t)^n$. So
$$\int_0^1x^{2n-1}(1-x^2)^p dx=-\int_1^0(1-t)^n t^pdt=\int_0^1(1-t)^nt^pdt=B(n+1,p+1)=\frac{n! \Gamma(p+1)}{\Gamma(p+n+2)}$$